# Why I can't write a value into the IORef but can read it

Tags: haskell, interpreter, unsafe-perform-io, ioref

In haskell, I need a global variable so I choose to use IORef slot, here is my plan:

```
memo :: IORef Int
memo = unsafePerformIO $ newRefInt 9999

evaluate ARGs s = do
  v <- Right $ unsafePerformIO $ readIORef memo
  val <- Right $ VInt v
  return $ (val, s)

evaluate (Call funcID exp) s = do
...
Right $ writeIORef memo 100
...
```

My plan is when the executer evaluates the "Call" node, it will save the parameter into the slot. Then when the "ARGs" node are evaluated, that memo slot would be read.

But whatever I do, I just can read 9999 but cannot write a new value into that slot.

Even I tried:

```
memo :: IORef Int
memo = unsafePerformIO $ newRefInt 9999

evaluate ARGs s = do
  Right $ writeIORef memo 100
  v <- Right $ unsafePerformIO $ readIORef memo
  val <- Right $ VInt v
  return $ (val, s)
```

It will still result that memo = 9999. Why?

Comment: There are very few acceptable uses of `unsafePerformIO`.  If you find yourself using it, find another way to do it using the `IO` monad.  It will cause more problems that it will solve in normal code.  It is only there for very specialized cases.

Comment: Recall that `unsafePerformIO` was only introduced with the _foreign_ function interface: to do pure computations in pure code where they belong, when the compiler can however not prove it to be correct because you're calling functions written in another (side-effectful) language.

Comment: In addition to other issues, you should add the pragma `{-# NOINLINE memo #-}`.  Without this, the compiler may (almost certainly will) inline references to `memo`, resulting in different parts of your code accessing different `IORef`s.

Answer (score 12):

Because writing is in the `IO` monad too. First off, that many `unsafePerformIO`s is just bad. `unsafePerformIO` **should not be used in normal code**.

Right now, you're creating an action to write to the `IORef` which is of type `IO ()`, wrapping it up in the `Right` constructor, and then throwing it away, you never actually use it.

You can't `unsafePerformIO` it either since you're not strict in the value of the `Either` value you constructed. This is why `unsafePerformIO` is bad, it's incredibly hard to reason about when/if things are going to happen.

Instead try

```
 evaluate ARGs s = do
    liftIO $ writeIORef memo 100
    v <- liftIO $ readIORef memo
    val <- return $ VInt v
    return $ (val, s)
```

And use the `EitherT` monad transform to stick `IO` in there.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez Yeah, I just forgot to edit it from the original snippet